# Spherical coordinates in surface integrals

Tags: surface-integrals

I am stuck on the following problem

Evaluate :

$$I=\iint x^2 y^2 z dS $$
where S is the positive side of lower half of the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = a^2$

I tried using spherical coordinates and their jacobians but cannot seem to find the answer which is $$I= \frac {2\pi a^7} {105}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What means ... positive side of lower half of the sphere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following transformation:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
x&=a\sin\phi\cos\theta\\
y&=a\sin\phi\sin\theta\\
z&=a\cos\phi
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$ and $\phi\in[-\frac{\pi}{2},0]$, then $dS=a^2\sin\phi\;d\phi\;d\theta$. Now
$$
\iint_Sx^2y^2z\:dS=a^7\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta\;d\theta\int_{-\pi/2}^0\sin^5\phi\cos\phi\;d\phi=a^7\bigg[\frac{\pi}{4}\bigg]\cdot\bigg[-\frac{1}{6}\bigg]=-\frac{\pi a^7}{24}.
$$
Note that 
$$\int_{-\pi/2}^0\sin^5\phi\cos\phi\;d\phi=\int_{-\pi/2}^0\sin^5\phi(\sin\phi)'\;d\phi=\bigg[\frac{1}{6}\sin^6\phi\bigg]_{-\pi/2}^0=-\frac{1}{6}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $z=-\sqrt{a^2-x^2-y^2}$ and $dS=\sqrt{1+z_x^2+z_y^2}dA$. which turn $$I=-a\iint_{R} x^2y^2dA.$$ Use polar co-ordinate.$x=r\cos\theta, y=r\sin \theta$. $dxdy=rdrd\theta$. $r$ varies from $0$ to $a$ and $\theta$ varies from $0$ to $2\pi$. Which turn $I=-a\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin^2\theta \cos^2\theta d\theta \int_{0}^a r^5 dr=\frac{-a^7}{6}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin^2\theta \cos^2\theta d\theta  =\frac{-a^7}{24}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin^2 2\theta d\theta=\frac{-a^7}{48}\int_{0}^{2\pi}({1-\cos4\theta}) d\theta=\frac{-a^7\pi}{24}$

Comment: I tried this method also ....... I am getting the same answer( a^2 )pi / 24

Comment: your answer must be wrong. power of $a$ must be $7$. It is easy to see.

Comment: Oh sorry my typo error it is (a^7) pi / 24

Comment: Textbook answer is wrong.

Comment: There are other questions also which are not reaching to their correct conclusion..... Should i post them too ?

Comment: And the solutions given are not like total outliers ..... They have the same variables as in the questions

Comment: which textbook?

Comment: Mathematical Analysis by SC Malik and Savita Arora page no. 668

Comment: Use standard books. Thomas Calculus is good.